# How do you hide something from the URL with htaccess

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

On my application i have a webshop with multiple items. For each item you are able to have different kind of colors. So the colors have to be in the url to send it as a parameter.

The moment you click on an item, you will get send to that item's page with the url *http://cmsproject.local/item/2/nocolor*. The **nocolor** is the thing i want to hide from the url, which would result looking something like this:
*http://cmsproject.local/item/2*.

If you have selected a color the last part of the url looks this "*/2136c7*". This is not a problem and should still be looking like this. Only when there is no color selected, the url should hide the **nocolor** part.

I have tried multiple forums, but none of them worked out for me. I have tried something like this: 
**RewriteRule ^2/nocolor/(.*)$ $1**. and this 
**RewriteRule ^/2/nocolor [L]**.

My htaccess file looks like this:

RewriteEngine On

```
# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^/2/nocolor [L]
```

With this I expected that the url would "hide" the *nocolor* part, instead nothing changed and it didn't displayed any error.

Comment: Ony for item with ID 2? Why are you that number including in htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly, I don't think you necessarily need to be handling this at the HTTP server level. From what I understand, you want a URL which can have an optional parameter as part of it.

Based on your example, my assumption is that the URL (with or without a color present) is handled by the same endpoint. So my suggestion is that you delegate that responsibility to the Laravel Router via [**optional route parameters**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#parameters-optional-parameters).

Here's an example of how you could handle that, showcased with a simple route closure (this can of course be a controller action method):

```
Route::get('item/{id}/{color?}', function ($id, $color = null) {
    // If the URL is "/items/2" then $color will be null
    // If the URL is "/items/2/2136c7" then $color will be '2136c7'
});
```

Using the example above you can handle both situations.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this in your laravel app, but in htaccess would the solution look like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/item/([0-9]+)/? /item/$1/nocolor
```

- `^` start of the match
- `?` optional
- `+` at least one occurence

Take look at RegEx for further uderstanding.